# Open modal only on one specific button

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have three buttons in React JS and I want two of them to open external links whereas one will open a modal. I'm having some trouble figuring out the logic for this and having the modal and links working. I think it's the way I'm calling in the props but am stuck on how to fix it. I have a reusable button component:

`ButtonComponent.jsx`

```
class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
   handleClick(props) {
    if (props.text.includes('Modal Button')) {
      return (
        props.openModal
      );
    }
    props.history.push(props.link);
  }

render() {
    return (
            <div>
               <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props)}>{this.props.text}</button>           
            </div>
    );
  }
}
}
```

This is the component where I will be using the buttons 
`ButtonRow.jsx`

```
class ButtonRow extends React.Component {
  openModal() {
    return (
        <ReusableModal
            header={'Title'}
            body={'Content'}
            button={'Open link'}
        />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                    <ButtonComponent text={'Modal Button'} openModal={this.openModal()} />
                    <ButtonComponent text={'Link Button'} link={'google.com'} />
                    <ButtonComponent text={'Link Button'} link={'google.com'} />
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am also using a Reusable Modal component that already has an `isOpen` and `isClosed` state written in it.

```
class ReusableModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpen() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
                {this.props.button}
            </Button>
            <Modal
                show={this.state.isOpen}
                onHide={this.handleClose}
            >
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>{this.props.header}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <div>
                       {this.props.body}
                    </div>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) App.js

 App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <ButtonComponent text={"Modal Button"} />
          <ButtonComponent text={"Link Button"} link={"google.com"} />
          <ButtonComponent text={"Link Button"} link={"google.com"} />
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2)ButtonComponent

```
  class ButtonComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  };

  handleClick(props) {
    if (props.text.includes("Modal Button")) {
      // props.openModal();
      this.setState({ show: true });
    } else {
      props.history.push(props.link);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.show && (
          <ReusableModal
            open={true}
            showBtn={false}
            close={() => {
              this.setState({ show: false });
            }}
            header={"Title"}
            body={"Content"}
            button={"Open link"}
          />
        )}
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props)}>
          {this.props.text}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2)Reusable Modal

```
  class ReusableModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.showBtn && (
      <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>{this.props.button}</Button>
    )}
        <Modal show={this.props.open} onHide={this.props.close}>
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title>{this.props.header}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body><div>{this.props.body}</div></Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.props.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Modal doesn't open when I click the first button

Comment: ReusableModal component added above

Comment: can you write this code in sandbox so that i can give you concrete implementation to your problem

Comment: Not sure what that means

Comment: i mean if your running code is available here https://codesandbox.io/, it would be easy for me to find flaw

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-payne-98vd9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: As ButtonComponent is meant to be reusable, I want to avoid using customized code such as  ```if (props.text.includes("Modal Button")) {
      props.openModal();
    }``` within the reusable component. Is there any way to do that without using customization, perhaps within App.js?

Comment: Check out new version.Are you okay with it?

Comment: I mean I do not want the line ```if (props.text.includes("Modal Button"))``` in the ButtonComponent because that only refers to one specific component when the entire ButtonComponent could be used to refer to anything.

Comment: Also, when I press the Modal Button, I get another button that shwos up and only after I press the second button, the modal appears. I want the modal to appear right as I click the first Modal Button

Comment: I have updated my answer which provides solution of your second question

Comment: To your first question, Reusable component do consist of if statements so that same component can show(render) different thing based on passed props from other component

Comment: Could you edit the answer so that I could have what my final three files would have? (ReusableModal, ButtonComponent, App.js)

Comment: Here you go bro :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The only problem left, however, is that the button that you commented out in ReusableModal, I still need that functionality for another component. I just didn't need it for this specific one I'm working on now.

Comment: Updated answer solves your problem. Simply pass (showBtn=false)  if u dont need button and (showBtn=true) if you want button